# Binary file fails to execute in linux though file is present

Tags: linux, shell

I have a binary called `testbin` in `/x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin`.

When I go to a different directory and try executing the binary as

```
$ /x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin
```

I get an error:

```
cannot find /x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin.bin
```

but when I am inside the `.jef` directory and execute it like

```
$ testbin
```

the binary executes

Why does it search for a `.bin` file in the first place?

Comment: You say the binary is called `testbin` but the error refers to `testbin.bin`. Which is it? Or more precisely, *how* are you trying to execute it?

Comment: yes the error says so. i am just  trying to execute it as bash-3.2$/x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin

Comment: post the output of `type -f testbin`

Comment: testbin is hashed (/usr/bin/testbin)

Comment: Apparently `-f` does the opposite in bash and zsh. Regardless, when you type `testbin` in your .jef folder, it's executing `/usr/bin/testbin`, not `.../.jef/testbin`. Do a `ls -l /x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin /x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin.bin` and `file /x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin`.

Comment: This is off-topic; belongs on [su]

Comment: ls -l/x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 smqaatnb gopher 409 May 20 14:35 /x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin

Comment: whereas ls on testbin.bin returns a no such file or directory

Comment: The file size (409 bytes) should be a prime indicator that this is, in fact, not a binary file, but is probably a short shell script that then attempts to call `testbin.bin`, but fails to properly locate the file and `cd` and/or execute it with a full/relative path as it needs to.

Comment: i just made a copy of  /usr/bin/testbin  and places it in .jef folder

Answer (score 2):

Since it is unlikely that `/x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef` is in your path, running `testbin` by itself when `/x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef` is the working directory is not the same as running `/x/eng/r1/scratch/user/.jef/testbin` from a different directory. Running `testbin` instead runs (from the sound of it) `/usr/bin/testbin`, which is a standalone binary. (It sounds like `.../.jef/testbin` is a just a wrapper (possibly even a shell script) that calls the missing `testbin.bin`.)

Comment: .../.jef/testbin  was just a copy of the /usr/bin/testbin